# How to count nested collection from database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm making my first Asp.net Mvc application - Forum System.
I'm trying to display how many posts and threads there are in sub category.

This are my tables:

```
public class Category
{
   private ICollection<SubCategory> subCategories;

   public Category()
   {
       this.subCategories = new HashSet<SubCategory>();
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories
   {
       get { return this.subCategories; }
       set { this.subCategories = value; }
   }                          
}


public class SubCategory
{
    private ICollection<Thread> threads;

    public SubCategory()
    {
        this.threads = new HashSet<Thread>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Thread> Threads
    {
        get { return this.threads; }
        set { this.threads = value; }
    }
}


public class Thread
{
    private ICollection<Post> posts;

    public Thread()
    {
        this.posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts
    {
        get { return this.posts; }
        set { this.posts = value; }
    }

    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; } 
}


public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int ThreadId { get; set; }

    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }

    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

this is my view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<ForumSystem.Web.ViewModels.Home.IndexCategoryViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container">
    @foreach (var category in Model)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <h5>@category.Name</h5>

            @foreach (var subCat in category.SubCategories)
            {
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h7>
                            <a href="/SubCategory/@subCat.Title">@subCat.Title</a>
                        </h7>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p>@subCat.Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p>@category.ThreadsCount threads</p>
                        <p>@category.PostsCount posts</p>
                    <div class="row">

                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

@category.ThreadsCount and PostsCount are not working.
I can get easy threads count in view with @subCategory.Threads.Count, but I can't get posts count.
In controller I have tried many things.
The code in the moment is :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var threadScount = this.Data
                           .SubCategories
                           .All()
                           .SelectMany(x => x.Threads)
                           .Count();

        var postsCount = this.Data
                        .Threads
                        .All()
                        .SelectMany(x => x.Posts)
                        .Count();

        var model = this.Data
                    .Categories
                    .All()
                    .Select(c => new IndexCategoryViewModel
                    {
                        Name = x.Name,
                        SubCategories = c.SubCategories,
                        ThreadsCount = threadScount,
                        PostsCount = postsCount,
                    })
                    .ToList();


        return this.View(model);
    }
```

But this gives me all threads and posts count, not specific for each subCategory.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the whole view? If so then you need to create a view model that represents what you want to display. In particular, CategoryViewModel should contain properties for its thread count and posts count

Comment: And do you really have a controller named `SubCategory` that has a method for every subcategory title (`<a href="/SubCategory/@subCat.Title">`)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create view models that represent what you want to display

```
public class SubCategoryVM
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public int ThreadsCount { get; set; }
  public int PostCount { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<SubCategoryVM> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = this.Data.Categories.Select(c => new CategoryVM
  {
    Name = c.Name,
    SubCategories = c.SubCategories.Select(s => new SubCategoryVM
    {
      Title = s.Title,
      Description = s.Description,
      ThreadsCount = s.Threads.Count,
      PostsCount = s.Threads.SelectMany(t => t.Posts).Count;
    })
  });
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<CategoryVM>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container">
  @foreach (var category in Model)
  {
    <div class="row">
      <h5>@category.Name</h5>
      @foreach (var subCategory in category.SubCategories)
      {
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="row">
            <h7>
              // The following line in your view makes no sense
              // <a href="/SubCategory/@subCat.Title">@subCat.Title</a>
              // Assuming you have method: public ActionResult Details(string title) in SubCategoryController, then
              @Html.ActionLink(subCategory.Title, "Details", "SubCategory", new { title = subCategory.Title }, null)
            </h7>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <p>@subCategory.Description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <p><span>@subCategory.ThreadCount</span><span>threads</span></p>
          <p><span>@subCategory.PostCount</span><span>posts</span></p>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
var model = this.Data
    .Categories
    .Select(c => new IndexCategoryViewModel
    {
        Name = c.Name,
        SubCategories = c.SubCategories,
        ThreadsCount = c.Threads.Count(),
        PostsCount = c.Threads.Sum(t => t.Posts.Count()),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Here you create nested queries to count threads and posts for each category. You don't need the `threadsCount` and `postsCount` since they store overall counts and not per-category counts.

**NOTE**

I assume that `Threads` property exists on category class and `Posts` property exists on thread class. Otherwise you'll need to have predicates to associate posts with threads and threads with categories. Most commonly they would be ids, in which case the code would look similar to this:

```
var model = this.Data
    .Categories
    .Select(c => new IndexCategoryViewModel
    {
        Name = c.Name,
        SubCategories = c.SubCategories,
        ThreadsCount = this.Data
            .Threads
            .Count(t => t.CategoryId == c.Id),
        PostsCount = this.Data
            .Posts
            .Count(p => this.Data
                .Threads
                .Any(t => p.ThreadId == t.Id && t.CategoryId == c.Id)
            ),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Notice that I also skipped all `.All()` calls since they seem redundant, although I'm not sure what they do so you can throw it back in there if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, also you will need to change the ViewModel to reflect requirements

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = from subCategory in this.Data.SubCategories
                select new SubCategoryViewModel
                {
                    Name = subCategory.Category.Name,
                    SubCategory = subCategory,
                    ThreadsCount = subCategory.Threads.Count(),
                    PostsCount = subCategory.Threads.SelectMany(c => c.Posts).Count(),
                })
                .ToList();


    return this.View(model);
}
```